# Slicer on custom date-quarter range

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI, my ideal solution is a between slicer with date values of the form yyyy-QQ where the default (THAT CAN BE MODIFIED) is the prior quarter and extends for the next year (e.g., 2022-Q1 to 2023-Q1), like so: [image]
I have a date table with dates, including quarters, and am open to achievable modifications on this theme, such as a start quarter and number of quarters, date slicer that defaults to quarter boundaries, etc.
Requirements:

1. Must use quarters
2. Quarters/range (including number of quarters) must be modifiable by user
3. Cannot use list or dropdown (my date range is over 50 years)
   Thanks for both ideas and code snippets!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up going with was to use a slicer named "Quarters From Today."  In my date table, I added a column to compute this value:

```
Date = ADDCOLUMNS(
  CALENDAR( DATE(2018, 01, 01), DATE(2032, 12, 31) ),
  "Quarters from Today", DATEDIFF(TODAY(), [Date], QUARTER) )
```

I then added a slicer on the Quarters from Today field:
[image]

And to assist the user, I added the dates to the chart title using `MIN('Date'[Date])` and `MAX('Date'[Date])`:
[image]